# laravel symlinks on a window machine

Tags: laravel, windows

Using a windows server, I have a laravel installation.
I have a storage folder that I have created on 'root/storage'
When I save images from the website, the images are stored in this folder.
I use this to save the files:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('course_badges/'.$pre_string . $request->file('badge')->getClientOriginalName(), File::get($request->file('badge')));
```

When I try to reference the file like so 'https://app.com/storage/file_name.jpg', laravel gives me a 'Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.'  error.

However is I copy the files to '/public/storage/'

The image is then referenced correctly.

I have run the: `php artisan symlink` function.
I have tried to run `ln -s ../storage/` command in powershell, but windows tells me that ln is not recognized.

What I am trying to achieve is to have my files saved in the root/storage folder (and sub folders)
and to reference them using https:app.nam/storage/file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I had simmilar issue**

as u mentioned file is stored in `root/storage` means problem with symlink between `root/storage` to `public/storage` to fix this

remove `storage` folder from public `dir`

> Note:- keep backup first

then run `php artisan storage:link`

it should work

Comment: Ah! that has solved the problem of the image auto copying to public/storage.  But it is not create another 'storage' folder and the images are not linking using https://app.name/storage/reference   But I am marking your answer as correct as it solved my original question.

Comment: it's not `auto copying` it store file in `root/storage` but inorder to access from url laravel create `symlink` bw those 2 folder so it should able to access from https://app.name/storage/reference